# Module not found: Can't resolve '@egjs/hammerjs' while installing React Native Gesture Handler

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I get the error

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@egjs/hammerjs'

while trying to import 'react-native-gesture-handler' in an Expo Run React Native app.

I've tried `expo install @types/hammerjs` and `expo install @types/hammerjs` and in my application `import hammer`, but it still throws the error.

I'm using Hammer.JS version `2.0.8` and React Native Gesture Handler version `1.5.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue and had to uninstall react-native-gesture-handler `npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler` and **install it via npm and not expo** `npm i react-native-gesture-handler`which is now version 1.6.1.

This worked for me, but it triggers a warning message `Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - react-native-gesture-handler - expected version range: ~1.5.0 - actual version installed: ^1.6.1
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]`

However, if you install react-native-gesture-handler with expo `expo install react-native-gesture-handler` you'll get the same `Module not found: Can't resolve '@egjs/hammerjs'` issue. Hence I guess this is a short term fix but is works.

My expo-cli is version 3.15.5

Here are my current dependencies 
  `"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.0.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1"
  },`

So you don't need to install @types/hammerjs as a dependency.

I hope it helps !

Comment: You're welcome ! Did you faced this issue while trying to run Expo on browser ?